# Q# Console Template DOTNET not working on MAC

Tags: visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, q#

```
$ dotnet new console -lang Q# --output Bell

Error: Invalid parameter(s):
-lang Q#
    'Q#' is not a valid value for -lang (language).
```

Run dotnet new console --help for usage information.
See https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-templates to learn how to install additional template packs.

I also tried running:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.2.x::2.0.0-*
```

But even this command could not add the project any idea how I can get this template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to run:

```
dotnet new -i "Microsoft.Quantum.ProjectTemplates::0.2-*"
```

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-installconfig?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vscode for more complete instructions.

Comment: Now, running `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Quantum.ProjectTemplates` works just fine. You have to first install the C# to Q# interop as detailed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/csharp?view=qsharp-preview